# Unable to remove accented special characters in a string despite using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, special-characters

I have the following code

```
import re
oldstr="HRÂ Director,Â LearningÂ"
newstr = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=&~|.!?,^]", " ", oldstr)
print(newstr)
```

The above code does not work.

Current result 
"HRÂ Director,Â LearningÂ"

Expected result
"HR Director, Learning"

How to achieve this ?

Comment: So, why not add `Â` to the character class? Or, better, fix the encoding issue.

Comment: Use: `re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]+|[-()"#/@;:<>{}\`+=&~|.!?,^]+', "", oldstr)` where `[^\x00-\x7f]` will match all non-ASCII characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew . Your solutions worked.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava your solution is elegant too.

Comment: @XPhyro I got my answer here. Thanks for pointing me to the link. The solution mentioned there didn work for me for some reason. I had a look at it before posting my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use:

```
import re
oldstr="HRÂ Director,Â LearningÂ"
newstr = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]+|[-()"#/@;:<>{}`+=&~|.!?,^]+', "", oldstr)
print(newstr)
```

**Output:**

```
HR Director Learning
```

`[^\x00-\x7f]` will match all non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method too:

```
def _removeNonAscii(s): 
    return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)
```

Here's how my piece of code outputs:

```
s = "HRÂ Director,Â LearningÂ"
def _removeNonAscii(s): 
    return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)

print(_removeNonAscii(s))
```

**Output:**

HR Director, Learning